# How do I link an handlebars page on a ejs page?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, express-handlebars

I have two pages:

```
1. landingPage.ejs
2. Checklist.handlebars
```

How do I redirect the user to the Checklist page when they click the link on the landingPage?

I have tried the code below, but received the error "Failed to lookup view "pages/Checklist" in views directory" despite Checklist.handlebars being in the pages directory.

landingPage.ejs:

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="/Checklist">CheckList</a>
```